# Parent is not fetching child entities in relationships using EntityManager.find

Tags: hibernate, fetch, find, relationship, children

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USR_TBL")
@Access(javax.persistence.AccessType.FIELD) 
Class UserEntity{
   @Id
   String usrIdNum

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="USR_ROLE", 
         joinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="USR_ID")}
    , inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID")}) 
    private Set<RoleEntity> roles;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ROLE_TBL")
@Access(javax.persistence.AccessType.FIELD) 
Class RoleEntity{
     @Id
     String id
  
     String desc

}
```

Inside my spring application respository class, i wrote this

```
@Override
    public UserEntity findUserByUserId(String userId) {
        UserEntity userEntity = this.em.find(UserEntity.class, userId); //em is entity manager
        int size = userEntity.getRoles().size(); // how come size is 0 ??
        return userEntity;
    }
```

Question is no matter how hard I try, the size of the roles is always 0.  How come?
Do note that i no intention to use other alternatives such as HQL or criteria API. As part of learning, i need to know why the above find() method not fetching the children.  I even enable the hibernate show sql, so that i can copy the sql produced by hibernate and execute it against the database, and yes, the user id I used in my application did have many roles.

**Update on 5 Jan 2022:**
I tentatively change my query to the below. It works!! The userEntity has size of 8 for its roles

```
UserEntity userEntity = this.em.createQuery("from UserEntity where id = 'MyAdmin1'", UserEntity.class).getResultList().get(0);
```

But when i change back to the below

```
UserEntity userEntity = this.em.find(UserEntity.class, "MyAdmin1");
```

The roles become empty (not null) again.
I can't close my question, as I still need to find the root cause why the this.em.find does not work as expected.

**Update on 6 Jan 2022:**
This issue also occur for @OneToMany, even if I try using EntityGraph (as suggested on internet) method.

**Update on 9 Jan 2022:**
I try the below annotations on the findById (inherited by CrudRepository):

This is not working

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = ....)
public Optional<UserEntity> findById(String userId);
```

This is working. Do note that i have defined the relevant queries on query.properties

```
    @Query
    public Optional<UserEntity> findById(@Param("userId") String userId);
```

One might think that perhaps @EntityGraph(attributePaths = ....) is typed wrongly.  I doubt so, cos when i try the exact same on findAll (inherited from JpaSpecificationExecutor), it works

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = ....)
public Page<UserEntity> findAll(Specification<UserEntity> spec, Pageable pageable);
```

Now I wonder if @EntityGraph only works for JPA related methods, but not methods from CrudRepository

Comment: "how hard I try" have you tried inserting data? (otherwise `size=0` is logical... how? please show!;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The data is already in the tables. And as mentioned above, i even use the sql generated by hiberate, and execute against the database, And the result did shows many roles for the specific user.But unfortunately, cos this database contains my company data, and hence I can't show on the web.

Comment: By the way, all the data in the db is inserted via sql script.

Comment: Cos I using Set, internet suggest overriding the hashCode and equals method of the RoleEntity..which I did.  But still size is 0

Comment: I have updated my question again to reflect new observation.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason.

1. I uses findById (inherited from Crud Repository), which is not correct. I should write my own custom query method, that is findByUsridNum, since the entity field name is usridNum, not id.  Now everything works as normal.
2. The funny thing is when I use findById, i notice the spring boot framework does not throw me error...but instead still continue to retrieve the record. The only catch is that it no longer fetch its children, no matter what i do (use EAGER fetching, use EntityGraph, etc...)